# How do I make a form with only hidden inputs inside a Bootstrap (4) modal submit on enter?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a form with only hidden inputs (and a hidden submit button) inside a Bootstrap modal. My intention is to have the user open the modal by clicking a button, and then have them press **enter** immediately after the modal is shown to submit the form.

Based on my research (and trial and error) I need to have a keypress handler inside the modal or form to handle the enter button and execute the form `submit()`. And in addition, I need to focus on the form after the modal is shown.

However, it seems like the focus mechanism is not working correctly. The enter submit does not work immediately after the modal is shown (and I call `form.focus()`). It does work, however, if I click on the modal/form after it is shown. But I want it to work without having to click on the modal.

Could I be missing something here? Or, is there a better way to do this altogether?

Here is my code sample. After clicking the button to show the modal, **enter** does not work. But if I click anywhere inside the modal, and then hit **enter**, it does work. I want **enter** to work without having to click inside the modal.

```js
$('#quickSwipeModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#quickSwipeForm').focus();
  }, 400);
});
$("#quickSwipeForm").keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#quickSwipeForm').submit();
  }
});
$('#quickSwipeForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('adding...');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top sub-menu">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#quickSwipeModal">Quick Swipe Mode</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="modal fade" id="quickSwipeModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="quickSwipeModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form id="quickSwipeForm" novalidate>
        <div class="modal-header" tabindex="-1">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="quickSwipeModalTitle" tabindex="-1">Quick Swipe Mode</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" tabindex="-1">
       <span aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">&times;</span>
      </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" tabindex="-1">
          <p tabindex="-1">Swipe ID cards to add notes instantly.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer" tabindex="-1">
          <input type="hidden" name="PatientId" tabindex="-1" />
          <input type="hidden" name="CreateDate" tabindex="-1" />
          <input type="submit" style="display: none" tabindex="-1" />
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" tabindex="-1">Done</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like your selecting the form with your keypress event listener, `$("#quickSwipeForm").keypress(...)` which might be why it has to be in `focus()` to work. Maybe you can use event delegation and select the body element to listen for a keypress... `$('body').on('keypress', function(){...})` and then check that the form is visible, and if it is, then submit it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding tabindex=0 to the form and check if your code works.

```
<form id="quickSwipeForm" tabindex="0" novalidate>
```

Comment: This isn't the behavior I want. This is just submitting the form automatically when it is shown. I want the form to be submitted **when pressing enter**, but only **after the form is shown**.

Comment: That worked! Not sure why, but that allowed the form to be focused programmatically.

Comment: @MattSpinks forms like divs, spans etc by default will not have focus, we need to set it explicitly via tabindex

Comment: I see. I think I remember that now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

> I want enter to work without having to click inside the modal.

Change from

```
    $("#quickSwipeForm").keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#quickSwipeForm').submit();
        }
    });
```

To:

```
    $(document).keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#quickSwipeForm').submit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I thought about doing this, but won't this submit the form even after the modal is hidden? I don't want the enter to submit when the modal is hidden. I only want enter to submit when the form is shown.